# How can I delete old logs in Log4php?

Tags: logging, delete-file, log4php

Is there any way to delete old logs in log4php? Or logs gets deleted after specific time duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the plain `LoggerAppenderFile`, then it is up to you to rotate the logfiles, which might be a good thing because it can be done without any impact on the running PHP application.

If you want log4php to do this, use either the `LoggerAppenderRollingFile` (creates a new logfile after a certain size, and deletes the oldest rotated) or `LoggerAppenderDailyFile` (created a new file based on the time).